# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CommentsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting Post expected, got String error. If someone can help me thanks in advance.

```
<% form_for :comment, :url=>{:controller=>"comments", :action=>"create"} do |f|%>
<p>
<%= f.label :body, "New Comment"%><br />
<%= f.text_area :body %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post, :value=>@post.id %>
</p>
<p><%= f.submit "Add Comment"%></p>
<% end%>

def create
   @comment = Comment.create(params[:comment])
   if @comment.save
      redirect_to(:controller=>"posts" ,:action=>'index')
   else
      redirect_to(:controller=>"posts" ,:action=>'show', :id=>"post.id")
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second redirect should be:

```
redirect_to(:controller=>"posts" ,:action=>'show', :id=> @comment.post.id)
```

Although, looking at this, you could definitely use some better patterns to clean things up. If you are using RESTful routes, I would change your create action to be:

```
def create
  @post = params[:id]
  @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to posts_url
  else
    redirect_to post_url(@post)
  end
end
```

This would allow you to remove the hidden field in your form since it should be getting passed through the URL as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, shouldn't you change `post.id` to `@post.id` (and maybe create a post object)?