# ActiveRecord Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two model class,

```
class Designation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_many :employee_details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employee_details
end
```

and

```
class EmployeeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Designation
  attr_accessible :bloodGroup, :dob, :doc, :doj, :empId, :name, :panNo, :status, :Designation
end
```

I have generated default scaffold for EmployeeDetail. from EmployeeDetail page when i tried to create and enter integer value in designation textbox, it gives me error
`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in EmployeeDetailsController#create
Designation(#81846160) expected, got String(#75419260)`.

can anyone help me to sortout this problem?
EmployeeDetailController#create:-
def create
    @employee_detail = EmployeeDetail.new(params[:employee_detail])

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @employee_detail.save
    format.html { redirect_to @employee_detail, notice: 'Employee detail was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @employee_detail, status: :created, location: @employee_detail }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @employee_detail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Please include the code of your `EmployeeDetailsController#create` method.

Comment: May be it's help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249856/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-in-commentscontrollercreate

Answer (score 1):

When you associate any model, you should use the lowercase version of the model name.

Change:

```
belongs_to :Designation
```

to:

```
belongs_to :designation
```

Comment: by doing this, it gives error in view. <%= f.text_field :Designation %> because view also have :Destination and it is auto generated. so i have to change in views also??

Comment: after changing belongs_to :Designation
to belongs_to :designation, it still showing the same error..

Comment: I think you are trying to work with nested forms, refer http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 which will help you. We should not use :Designation in view.